# If $R/J(R)$ is simple then $R$ is local

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

The question is what I said in the title :-

> If $R/J(R)$ is simple then $R$ is local.

where $J(R)$ is Jacobson radical.

I only have the idea about the converse ( If $R$ is is local then $R/J(R)$ will be a field and eventually simple).

Comment: The answer seems to assume that $R$ is commutative. If you are content with this, then why don't mention it explicitly in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $R/J(R)$. It has a maximal ideal, but by simplicity, its maximal ideal is $0$, i.e. it is a field. But this implies

$$ J(R) = \bigcap _ {m \in \textrm{Max} (R) } m $$

is a maximal ideal. Yet by definition, it is contained in all maximal ideals of the ring $R$ and so indeed it is the unique maximal ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not totally sure if you intended to talk about commutative rings only, or not. For one thing, it's a little strange to talk about simple commutative rings since

> Proposition: a commutative simple ring is a field.
>   Proof: if $x$ is nonzero, $xR=R$, hence x is invertible.

For noncommutative rings, it is certainly correct to say that $R/J(R)$ is a division ring iff $R$ is a local ring.

$R/J(R)$ being simple does not cut it in general. A square matrix ring over a division ring is an example where $R/J(R)$ is simple but not local.